# Is it necessary to set a different ttl before change a Route53 DNS record value?

Tags: domain-name-system, cache, amazon-route53, resolv.conf, ttl

The first time create the Route53 DNS record with a load balancer origin DNS name with ttl 1 day.

After some days, we want to change the value to another load balancer origin DNS name. Do we need to set the target DNS record's ttl to a short time such as 1 hour first? Then after 1 hour change the DNS value. Does it can refresh its DNS cache and update to new record perfectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, just change the record. It often takes a lot less time to propagate changes, sometimes in just minutes.